# Up to how fast can the Panic Attack's reload and firerate be?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there a cap at hp so that eventually you will lose enough health to gain the most optimal firerrate and reload speed? Or does it still scale, even when you are down to 1 hp?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems to go up in increments.  Then again, I was testing it in PropHunt[1] at the time, which deals 8 damage to you for every shot you fire.  [1] Because I'm the current maintainer of TF2 PropHunt

Comment: As far as I know, nobody yet have discovered the forumla for the loading/firing rate for panic attack at 1 hp yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as far as I can tell, it does continue to scale firerate down to 1 HP.

I didn't find any specific stats, although by eyeballing it from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a37cYMvUlBM) (see around 1:25), it appears to be twice as fast at 1 HP than it is at full HP.

(Keep in mind this isn't hard evidence, only an educated guess.)